# Application current path c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oledb

I'm trying to point to my database, the application is working, but I'm getting an error in the xaml binding.

```
            con = new OleDbConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Database\\Baza_Info.accdb"
        };
```

It's working fine, but I'm getting error. 
This code is in a usercontrol.
On another wpf window I got this:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:AdminViewModels/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

It throws the error here, and it says the path to my visual studio installation Common7/IDE/Database is not valid. Select a path that's spelled correctly blabla connected to the server.

help please.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it seems that it doesn't address the actual issue. Nonetheless, I would still advise that you use `ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Baza_Info.accdb"` to specify your connection string.

Comment: As for the issue, can you please provide the exact error message and also the stack trace for the exception? This is a bit of a guess but do you have the VS hosting process enabled in the project properties? It's not available for WPF projects in VS 2017 but I'm not sure what version you're using and whether it was available in older versions. If it is enabled, try disabling it.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Your answer was correct one, I just rushed with my reply.

Comment: That's good news. I've undeleted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data file is under the same folder as the executable then use "|DataDirectory|" for the folder path.

```
con = new OleDbConnection
{
    ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Baza_Info.accdb"
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working, but I still get the error in the form i'm displaying my database